# Jour/journée etc with indefinite adjectives

Tags: grammaire, choix-de-mot

I read that you should use the duration words (journée, matinée etc.) with indefinite adjectives on the About.com French site. However, I've seen many cases of use with the division word, and indeed a Google search shows many more results for them with, as an example, "chaque". The only exception is with année.

So I'm wondering which I should use with "chaque" and more generally with indefinite adjectives? Is there really a set rule or can either be used?

I.e: is there a rigid, definitive rule to decide whether to use either duration words (année, soirée, journée) or what I call division words (an, soir, jour) with indefinite adjectives (i.e d'autres, certains, quelques, chaque) or are they interchangeable? If they're interchangeable, how should I decide which to use?

Comment: Can you give examples? I could correct those if needed, but the current description is a little abstract for me :-)

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear in my question.

Comment: What I meant was is there a rigid, definitive rule to decide whether to use either duration words (année, soirée, journéé)  or what I call division words (an, soir, jour) with indefinite adjectives (i.e d'autres, certains, quelques, chaque) or are they interchangeable?If they're interchangeable, how should I decide which to use?

Answer (score 1):

There is no rigid rule and the duration and division words aren't always interchangeable.

*Chaque jour*    (very common: usually means "every day" but can mean "each day" too)
*Chaque journée* (possible; usually means "each day" but can mean "every day" too)

*Chaque matin*   (possible, we often prefer *tous les matins*)
*Chaque matinée* (possible, = "each morning")

*Chaque soir*    (possible, we often prefer *tous les soirs*)
*Chaque soirée*  (possible, = "each evening")

*Chaque an*      (almost impossible in modern French, we say either *tous les ans* or *chaque année* but *chaque nouvel an* is possible)
*Chaque année*   (has both meanings)

Both *d'autres/certains/quelques jours* and *d'autres/certaines/quelques journées* are possible.

Using *matins* and *soirs* is rare with *d'autres, certains,* very rare with *quelques*.

*D'autres, certains,* and *quelques* are never used with *ans* but we say *d'autres/certaines/quelques années*.

Answer (score 0):

"*Chaque jour*" is much, much more common.

"*Chaque journée*" looks grammatical, I could see it used in sentences like "*chaque journée passée loin de toi...*", but it's pretty rare.

[Here's](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=chaque+jour%2C+chaque+journ%C3%A9e&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cchaque%20jour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cchaque%20journ%C3%A9e%3B%2Cc0) some data to give you an idea.

I think I didn't misunderstand your question, it wasn't very clear.